# How can I get the device's orientation if its locked to portrait?

Tags: android, xamarin, rotation, orientation

I have set the ScreenOrientation in MainActivity, because I don't want the app to rotate.

```
ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait
```

With this I always get 0.

```
DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Rotation
```

How can I get the rotation of the phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set in `manifest.xml` file if you want to lock your screen orientation

```
<activity
   android:name="...YourActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

You can get the orientation

```
resources.configuration.orientation
or
windowManager.defaultDisplay.rotation
```

Comment: Thank you, and can I lock the orientation in just one page?

Comment: Yes, you can lock for one activity and their fragments